# Redefinition error (C2365) in C++/CLI caused by Babel Obfuscator

Tags: c#, c++-cli, obfuscation, redefinition, babeljs

When I obfuscate my assebly (DLL with custom control) written in C#. It works in both C# and VB.NET apps.

When I use the DLL from C++/CLI app, however, errors like this appear during build:

> error C2365: 'ComponentOwl::BetterSplitButton::BetterSplitButton::e' : redefinition; previous definition was 'property'

The "e" refers to either internal enum member, private property name etc.

Is it possible to instruct Babel obfuscator to not generate duplicate names (I have not found such switch). Or is it avoidable from code?

Comment: If your C++/CLI assembly was not built with /clr:pure (i.e. it's not 100% managed like C# and VB.NET ones), it might be because Babel Obfuscator only supports managed assemblies. Not sure about that since I never used Babel, but I've done C++/CLI for a while and most tools don't support it very well.

Comment: The assembly is in pure managed code (C#). The problem appears in test app, which uses the assebmly and the app is C++/CLI.

Comment: Your C++/CLI app, is it built with the /clr:pure switch? (Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults->Common Language Runtime Support)

Comment: Yes, it is built with /clr:pure by default. The problem relates to the DLL which is not part of the build - I just reference it and the errors come from there.

Comment: Someone else had [the same problem](http://www.digitalrune.com/Support/Forum.aspx?forumid=18&postid=1730&scope=posts) as well, but the company have not revealed what kind of sorcery they used to suppress this error.

Comment: Throw away tools that are not fit for their job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel.NET Support reproduced the problem and suggested to add command-line parameter:

```
--namelength 4
```

So the name conflict will be less probable.

They tested the non-working solution and found that obfuscated assembly has no metadata errors, but the C++/CLI compiler still complains there are two or more different symbols with the same name in a given type.